# Database not updating when using PHP var's

Tags: php

I am doing some simple PHP and SQL for the first time in quite a while, but for some reason am not getting it to work. When I provide fixed values it all works fine, but as soon as I replace them with variables my code fails. I have checked and it seems that the variables have proper values in them:

This works:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

     if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $ID = $_GET['id'];
        $newStock = $_GET['stockcount'] - 1;
        mysqli_query($con,'UPDATE products SET stockcount = "3" WHERE id = "1"');   
     }
    else
        echo "Invalid item";


    mysqli_close($con);

    header('Location: browse.php');
?>
```

But not this:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx","xxx");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

     if(isset($_GET['id'])){
        $ID = $_GET['id'];
        $newStock = $_GET['stockcount'] - 1;
        mysqli_query($con,'UPDATE products SET stockcount = "'+$newStock+'" WHERE id = "'+$ID+'"'); 
     }
    else
        echo "Invalid item";


    mysqli_close($con);

    header('Location: browse.php');
?>
```

Do I need to do something with the variables, or am I doing something else wrong? As always, any advice would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Add this: `echo('UPDATE products SET stockcount = "'+$newStock+'" WHERE id = "'+$ID+'"');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" + " is not used for concatenate string in PHP as you did

```
 mysqli_query($con,'UPDATE products SET stockcount = "'+$newStock+'" WHERE id = "'+$ID+'"');
```

it should be as

```
 mysqli_query($con,'UPDATE products SET stockcount = "'.$newStock.'" WHERE id = "'.$ID.'"');
```

Comment: What a noob mistake :D Thanks man, really appreciate it. It is working perfectly now!

Comment: Thats ok and by mistake only we learn.. as they say if you dont commit mistake means u never tried and you tried before posting on SO :)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqli_query($con,'UPDATE products SET stockcount = "'.$newStock.'" WHERE id = "'.$ID.'"');
```

This isn't javascript. Connotate with `.` not `+`. Better yet, just pass it in string by  using double-quotes!

```
mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE products SET stockcount = '$newStock' WHERE id = '$ID'");
```